# Python - Script run as Upstart job may need raw_input at some point

Tags: python, linux, google-api, upstart

I have a script that performs oauth for google calendar api access.

I am trying to run this job as an upstart job with a time sleep while loop inside of it.

It works perfectly fine, however I was considering what if at some point the refresh token requests no longer work. I will have to store the code again but I will need manual input in the terminal at some point.

I tried a test of running an upstart job like so:-

/etc/init/testing.conf :-

```
description "testing"
author "Tester"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
chdir /home/tester/Scripts
exec python testinput.py
```

/home/tester/Scripts/testinput.py :-

```
authorize_url = 'http://google.com' # Just an Example
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
print code
```

My question is - How Can I get the called python script to print and then accept raw_input from the terminal if required?

Comment: If you're the one writing the script, can you make a version that doesn't require `raw_input()`?

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to call python script testinput.py to print what ? You are already accepting input from terminal by using `raw_input()`. Don't say you want to print code (i.e., last line in the python script) before accepting in terminal !! That's crazy  !

Comment: It's really not that complicated. I have a script that puts itself into a while loop, which is always evaluated as True unless an exception is thrown. At the start of the main flow of the script It performs auth with google and MAY require a new code from google (at the moment it hasnt expired from initially storing it) but later down the line it might need a new code inputted when the script is started in the future. **bold**The underlying question here is, why does a script run as an upstart job not print/accept raw_input from the terminal it is being run in?*